# How to install Swampy in Atom?

Tags: python, python-3.x, atom-editor, swampy

Since a week ago I am learning Python with the O'Reilly book for beginners. 
Sadly I am totally stuck at the beginning of chapter 4. Where I have to install the swampy package. I am using the atom text editor to code and Python 3.x. I have no idea what everything means.

Comment: We can't help you if we don't know what the problem is. Can you paste the error output that you get when you try to install into your question?

Comment: I get this when I am trying to do it like its explained.

Comment: [Command: python3 -u /Users/julianbickel/Documents/Python/Learning/Test1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/julianbickel/Documents/Python/Learning/Test1", line 1, in <module>
    from swampy.Turtleworld import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'swampy'
[Finished in 0.074s]

Comment: I don't know how to add the module or package, couldn't find the solution.

Comment: In your terminal, install it by executing `pip install swampy`.  Some info about the package on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/swampy/), which is where most python packages are install from.

Comment: So I guess I got that, pip is installed and when I execute 'pip install swampy' this appears 'error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/swampy': Permission denied'. Is it maybe because the of the Python version?

Comment: You probably need to install it as sudo/administrator (I'm not a mac user).  Note that you sat you are using Python 3, but your pip error references Python 2.  So maybe try `python3 -m pip install swampy` first, which should install the package for Python 3, and may not requires admin rights.

Comment: nice that worked, now its written that I need Tkinter and I tried to install like swampy and looked for downloads in the inter net but couldn't finde any

Comment: You may already have it.  Otherwise I think that's a new question.

Comment: ok I guess I will make it from here, thank you very much you really helped me a lot and saved my evening. greetings from Germany.